# Erro no Hadoop ao procurar classe Java

Tags: java, centos, path, hadoop

Estou tendo problemas para configurar o ambiente Hadoop.
Estou fazendo uma instalação do zero em uma máquina CentOS 6.7.

Ao tentar executar qualquer comando hadoop, como por exemplo:

```
hdfs namenode -format
hadoop claspath
hadoop version
```

Recebo a mensagem de erro:

> Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal
>   ‐Djava.library.path=.home.hadoop.install.hadoop-2.7.1.lib

Abaixo minhas conf:

```
[hadoop@node1 hadoop]$ cat **hadoop-env.sh**
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101"
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS ‐Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/hadoop‐2.7.1/etc/hadoop"

[hadoop@node1 hadoop]$ cat **core-site.xml** 
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/hadoop‐2.7.1/tmp</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Variáveis do HADOOP

```
export HADOOP_INSTALL="/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1"
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="‐Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101"


PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/bin:/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/sbin


JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101
```

Caminho do Hadoop

```
[hadoop@node1 hadoop]$ pwd

/home/hadoop/install/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop
```

Comment: Bá, filho. Dá uma formatadinha nesse pergunta aí, por favor.

Comment: Publiquei sem querer.... to editando... desculpe

Comment: Pede desculpa não, acontece. Só queria dar um toque mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Va para:

```
cd /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/
vi hadoop-env.sh
```

Descomente o `export JAVA_HOME=`

acrescentar o `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk`

fazer o mesmo para o `export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop`

O mesmo precisa ser feito nos nodes-slave

```
## Iniciar o HDFS
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

Comment: 1 - para formatar o texto use [MarkDown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). 2- O `JAVA_HOME` dele não está comentado???